# The following classes could not be found - XML rendering ERROR

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to do preview of my activity_main.xml file but it give me error saying " The following classes could not be found "

```
  The following classes could not be found:

- com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view.BottomBar  (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Tip: Try to build the project.

Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

I tried to add class and now it says " It already contains class named BottomBar.

This is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_container"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottombar_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottombar_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_shadow_up"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottombar_height"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Comment: Please post your error log

Comment: The following classes could not be found:

- com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view.BottomBar  (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

    Tip: Try to build the project.

    Tip: Try to refresh the layout.